# Insertion order of a list based on order of another list

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, functional-programming, akka

I have a sorting problem in Scala that I could certainly solve with brute-force, but I'm hopeful there is a more clever/elegant solution available.  Suppose I have a list of strings in no particular order:

```scala
val keys = List("john", "jill", "ganesh", "wei", "bruce", "123", "Pantera")
```

Then at random, I receive the values for these keys at random (full-disclosure, I'm experiencing this problem in an akka actor, so events are not in order):

```scala
def receive:Receive = {
  case Value(key, otherStuff) => // key is an element in keys ...
```

And I want to store these results in a `List` where the `Value` objects appear in the same order as their `key` fields in the `keys` list.  For instance, I may have this list after receiving the first two `Value` messages:

```scala
List(Value("ganesh", stuff1), Value("bruce", stuff2))
```

`ganesh` appears before `bruce` merely because he appears earlier in the `keys` list. Once the third message is received, I should insert it into this list in the correct location per the ordering established by `keys`.  For instance, on receiving `wei` I should insert him into the middle:

```scala
List(Value("ganesh", stuff1), Value("wei", stuff3), Value("bruce", stuff2))
```

At any point during this process, my list may be incomplete but in the expected order.   Since the keys are redundant with my `Value` data, I throw them away once the list of values is complete.

Show me what you've got!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a ListMap instead of a list of tuples to store values while they're gathered, this could work.  ListMap preserves insertion order.

```
class MyActor(keys: List[String]) extends Actor {

  def initial(values: ListMap[String, Option[Value]]): Receive = {
    case v @ Value(key, otherStuff) =>
      if(values.forall(_._2.isDefined))
        context.become(valuesReceived(values.updated(key, Some(v)).collect { case (_, Some(v)) => v))
      else
        context.become(initial(keys, values.updated(key, Some(v))))
  }

  def valuesReceived(values: Seq[Value]): Receive = { } // whatever you need

  def receive = initial(keys.map { k => (k -> None) })

}
```

(warning: not compiled)

Comment: Holy crap, never knew about `ListMap`.  I'm from a Java background and I've long wished Scala had an immutable `LinkedHashMap`. LOL

Comment: Both answers were outstanding, but it just happens that I went with the `ListMap` approach because it made more sense in my case.  I defined my map as `ListMap[String, Option[Value]]` initializing all values to `None`.  I fill them in with `Some[Value]` as they come in.  Thanks to both @Ryan and @RexKerr!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want no worse than `O(n log n)` performance.  So:

```
val order = keys.zipWithIndex.toMap
var part = collection.immutable.TreeSet.empty[Value](
  math.Ordering.by(v => order(v.key))
)
```

Then you just add your items.

```
scala> part = part + Value("ganesh", 0.1)
part: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Value] = 
  TreeSet(Value(ganesh,0.1))

scala> part = part + Value("bruce", 0.2)
part: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Value] =
  TreeSet(Value(ganesh,0.1), Value(bruce,0.2))

scala> part = part + Value("wei", 0.3)
part: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Value] = 
  TreeSet(Value(ganesh,0.1), Value(wei,0.3), Value(bruce,0.2))
```

When you're done, you can `.toList` it.  While you're building it, you probably don't want to, since updating a list in random order so that it is in a desired sorted order is an obligatory `O(n^2)` cost.

---

Edit: with your example of seven items, my solution takes about 1/3 the time of Jean-Philippe's.  For 25 items, it's 1/10th the time.  1/30th for 200 (which is the difference between 6 ms and 0.2 ms on my machine).

Comment: I considered creating an `Ordering` but felt it might be too costly.  I see you've already thought it through before.  Good info!

Comment: @barnesjd - Creating an `Ordering` takes a few tens of nanoseconds.  Whether you are better off creating the hash map (takes about a microsecond) or just traverse the list depends on the length of the list.

Comment: Great solution! Mine has absolutely nothing better than this, so I’ll delete it.